# how to use bind-once or angular-once in element attributes

Tags: angularjs

Can I prevent angular watcher creation for element attributes using bind-once or angular-once directive?

I am using [Angular Once](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once) directive.

`How to use in following`

```
<div contentKey={{conKey}}></div>
```

`This working fine`

**Before Angular Once**

```
<div>{{conKey}}</div>
```

**After Angular Once**

```
<div><any once-text="conKey"></any></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the angular-once [api documentation](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once), attributes can be "bound once" using the following syntax: `once once-attr-*="value"`

So for your attribute, it would be:
`<div once once-attr-contentKey="conKey"></div>`

This is a little strange, because the parallel angular directive (ng-attr) can accept an expression in double curly braces (like you are trying to do).
`<div ng-attr-contentKey={{conKey}}></div>`

[Here is a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/sbnogakOY2WQuYYALZ9T) comparing the two.

Comment: Lib author here :) It's little strange, but adding interpolation ({{ }}) automatically adds watchers and lib is all against that, hope makes sense